# Program not outputting the correct standard deviation. Also, problems with validation

Tags: c++, function, validation, loops

My program currently has two problems. I am not getting the correct standard deviation when I try to run my program and also, I am unsure about how to implement a way to validate the user's input if they enter anything other than a double value. How would I go about fixing this? Thanks. My code is a bit messy, and I'd like suggestions on how to make it nicer if possible. The program I will post does not run, so if you want it to compile and run, uncomment out the inputs and comment the validation out. Thanks. The standard deviation I get is always below the actual standard deviation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <math.h>

double average(std::vector<double> & values) {  // The Average function. Obtainin by accumulation method.
double sum = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0.0);
double average = sum/values.size();
return average;
}





double square(int x) { // Square function. Just x*x. The simplist.
double squared = x*x;
return squared;
}






double stddeviation (std::vector<double> & values) { 
double lessmean;
double totalsquare;
double variance;
double standev;
std::vector<double> lessmeanvector; // Subtracting average from each number in the vector.
for (int i = 0; i<values.size(); i++) {
    lessmean = (values.at(i)-average(values));
    lessmeanvector.push_back(lessmean);
    }
//std::vector<double> squaredvector; // Squaring each number in the vector.
for (int i = 0; i<lessmeanvector.size(); i++) {
    totalsquare+= square(lessmeanvector.at(i));
    }   
variance = (totalsquare/(values.size())-1);
standev = pow(variance,0.5);
std::cout<<"The standard deviation is "<<standev<<".\n";
}







int main() {

int total; // Decleration of main variables.
double numbers;
std::cout<<"How many numbers would you like to enter in?\n"; 
int total = 0;
    while(!(std::cin >> total)){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
    }
//std::cin>>total;
std::cout<<"Enter "<<total<<" numbers in now.\n";

std::vector<double>values;
for(int i = 0; i<total; ++i) {
    while(!(std::cin >> numbers)){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    //std::cin>>numbers;
    values.push_back(numbers);
    }
std::cout<<"The average is "<<average(values)<<".\n";
stddeviation(values);

}
```

Comment: `variance = (totalsquare/(values.size())-1);` Your parentheses are in the wrong place. You divide `totalsquare` by `values.size()`, then subtract one from the result. Whereas I think you meant to divide `totalsquare` by `values.size()-1`

Answer (score 1):

One way to validate numbers is to read the number and then read the following whitespace. At that point you should have read all the characters. If not you have some extra characters at the end. But you need to do that from an input that can run out (std::cin goes on forever without user intervention).

So what I do is read in the whole line as a string and use a `std::istringstream` to convert and validate the input like this:

```
double numbers;

for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);)
{
    if((std::istringstream(line) >> numbers >> std::ws).eof())
        break;

    std::cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
}
```

It's not perfect because if you enter only spaces it succeeds. You need to add an extra check for that. For that I usually employ a string `trim()` function to remove surrounding whitespace characters (spaces and tabs etc...).

```
// remove surrounding whitespace
std::string& trim(std::string& s, char const* ws = " \t")
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(ws));
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(ws) + 1);
    return s;
}
```

Giving:

```
double numbers;

for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);)
{
    if(!trim(line).empty())
        if((std::istringstream(line) >> numbers).eof())
            break;

    std::cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
}
```

Now you don't need to skip the whitespace at the end of the input because you already trimmed it.