# How to detect floats when input is expected to be integer?

Tags: c++, user-input

How can I detect when a float number is inputted ?

I have written a program as below.
When inputting values for the number of quarters such as 5.
The output is 5. Which is expected.

When I input 5.5
The output is 5. This is incorrect as it's impossible to get 0.5 of a quarter.

Is this an issue with the way, values are interpreted in c++? How could I detect that the number is a float and not an integer number?

```
int calculation()
{
   int quarters = 0;
   cout << "Number of quarters:";
   cin >> quarters;

   cout << "the number of quarters you have: " << quarters;
}
```

**Full Implementation**

```
int calculation()
{
    float total;

    int quarters = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int pennies = 0;

    std::string input_quarters;
    std::string input_nickels;
    std::string input_dimes;
    std::string input_pennies;

    // reading to a string will read to end of line
    //quarters
    std::cout << "Number of quarters: ";
    std::cin >> input_quarters;

    std::cout << "Number of nickels: ";
    std::cin >> input_nickels;

    std::cout << "Number of Dimes: ";
    std::cin >> input_dimes;

    std::cout << "Number of pennies: ";
    std::cin >> input_pennies;

    // Allow 1 or more characters in range '0'-'9' until end of string
    std::regex numbers_only("[0-9]+$");

    // check if input matches pattern
    if (std::regex_match(input_quarters, numbers_only) && std::regex_match(input_nickels, numbers_only) && std::regex_match(input_dimes, numbers_only) && std::regex_match(input_pennies, numbers_only))
    {
        // convert string to int explicitly
        quarters = std::stoi(input_quarters);
        std::cout << "quarters now = " << quarters;
        total = quarters / 4 + (fmod(quarters, 4) * 0.25);

        nickels = std::stoi(input_nickels);
        std::cout << "Nickels now = " << nickels;
        total = total + nickels / 20 + (fmod(nickels, 20) * 0.05);

        dimes = std::stoi(input_dimes);
        std::cout << "Dimes now = " << dimes;
        total = total + dimes / 10 + fmod(dimes, 10) * 0.1;

        pennies = std::stoi(input_pennies);
        std::cout << "pennies now = " << pennies;
        total = total + pennies / 100 + fmod(pennies, 20) * 0.01;

        std::cout << "Total $ = " << total;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "input was not a whole number";
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: After successfully reading an integer, if a float was entered, the next character read will be a "." (subject to locale) followed by another integer.

Comment: This is about entering a `double` but the same principle applies to ntegers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260058/program-not-outputting-the-correct-standard-deviation-also-problems-with-valid/46260139#46260139

Comment: Read input as a `std::string`  (e.g. using `std::getline()`).   Check the contents of the string to determine if it contains characters you wouldn't expect in a non-integral value (e.g.  sign characters after the first character, non-digits, etc).   If it does contain such characters, either discard or correct the input.   Once you have a string that doesn't contain invalid characters, parse to obtain an integral value.    This way you can detect if (say) the user enters "23.4" or "hello world", and take appropriate corrective action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

bool is_valid_coin_amount(const std::string& input)
{
    // Allow 1 or more characters in range '0'-'9' until end of string
    // only initialize regex once by making it static (optimization)
    static std::regex numbers_only("[0-9]+$");
    return std::regex_match(input, numbers_only);
}

auto input_amount(const std::string& coin_type)
{
    std::string input;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number of " << coin_type << " : ";
        std::cin >> input;

        if (!is_valid_coin_amount(input))
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Input is not a valid amount, " << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return std::stoul(input); // amount is always positive so use unsigned type
}

double convert(int value, int scale)
{
    auto v = static_cast<double>(value);
    auto s = static_cast<double>(scale);
    return (v / scale) + (std::fmod(v, scale) / scale);
}


double calculate_total()
{
    double total{ 0.0 };

    int quarters = input_amount("quarters");
    int nickels = input_amount("nickels");
    int dimes = input_amount("dimes");
    int pennies = input_amount("pennies");

    std::cout << "quarters = " << quarters << std::endl;
    total += convert(quarters, 4);

    std::cout << "Nickels = " << nickels << std::endl;
    total += convert(nickels, 20);

    std::cout << "Dimes = " << dimes << std::endl;
    total += convert(dimes, 10);

    std::cout << "Pennies = " << pennies << std::endl;
    total += convert(pennies, 100);
    //total = total + pennies / 100 + fmod(pennies, 20) * 0.01f; <<== is the 20 here correct? if so convert must be modified a bit

    std::cout << "Total $ = " << total;

    return total;
}

int main()
{
    auto total = calculate_total();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes the total line you are correct must be:
`total = total + pennies /100 + fmod(pennies, 100)*0.01f;`

Answer (score 3):

One way you could solve it is by retrieving a string from the user and try to convert it with `std::stoi`.

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
std::size_t pos{0};
int val = std::stoi(str, &pos);
```

If `pos` isn't equal to `str.size()`, it means some characters were discarded, so the user probably didn't give a proper integer value.

Example here:
https://godbolt.org/z/cvPKcsTx4

Comment: Yup also a good one, but also catch (const std::out_of_range& e), std::stoi can throw that exception too. 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol/
Note : I usually prefer error handling with exceptions, it ties in much better with c++. Just decided for simplicity to use a non-exception example :)

Comment: About exception safe programming, I recommend the exceptional C++ books from Herb Sutter. When they came out they were game changers for me, started using exceptions and never looked back :)

Answer (score 1):

This progam shows what happens first(as Galik mentioned reading stopped at .)
Then it shows how you can check your full input before making an int out of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // piece of code showing what happens in the orignal code

    int quarters = 0;
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Number of quarters (enter 5.5 here) : ";
    std::cin >> quarters;

    std::cout << std::endl << "remaining input : ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "'" << input << "' ";

    std::cout << "the number of quarters you have: " << quarters << std::endl << std::endl;

    // reading to a string will read to end of line
    std::cout << "Number of quarters (with input checking) : ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "Your full input = " << input << std::endl;

    
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // piece of code with input checking

    std::regex numbers_only("[0-9]+$"); // Allow 1 or more characters in range '0'-'9' until end of string

    // check if input matches pattern
    if (std::regex_match(input, numbers_only))
    {
        //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
        // convert string to int explicitly
        quarters = std::stoi(input);
        std::cout << "quarters now = " << quarters;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "input was not a whole number" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks: this helped with my understanding.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. I just hope the regex didn't scare you.

Comment: Hi I think I have implemented the method shown above. I just wanted to know if there's a better way off reducing my if statement ?
Yes regrex didn't scare me.
Refer to main post.

Comment: I've added a solution below, that uses less duplication of code  (which is always better). In my opinion putting even a few lines in a function and giving it a clear name will make the main part of your program alsmost human readable. (And thus easier to maintain)