# How can I validate that an user enter a value (int) instead of skip with the enter key

Tags: c++

When I press the enter key without entered a value nothing else happens, just like if the program would be freezed, no more do-while loop until I enter a int value. How can I fix that?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void menu(int option)

int main(){
    int op{0};

    do{
        cout << setw(20) << "BMI Calculator" << endl;
        cout << "1. Personal Information" << endl;
        cout << "2. Physical Information" << endl;
        cout << "3. Calculate BMI" << endl;
        cout << "4. Result" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl;


        cin >> op;

        if (cin.good()){
            menu(op);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

    } while (op != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that when I don't enter any value in 'cin >> op;' the program gets into de else statement and then start the loop again printing the options.
Instead of that the loop is kind of freezed until I enter a number.

Thanks guys, I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Change `int op{0};` to `std::string op;`. Use `std::getline(std::cin, op);` to read the line.

Comment: `cin >> op;` will ignore all whitespace, that includes hitting enter, until something is input. Instead you want `std::getline` to read a line into a `std::string` and then to transform the `string`, if there's anything in the `string` to transform, into an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! But if I had to implement the same validation to know if the user entered, for example, his height instead of just skipping. How can I do that? Because this is kind of the real problem that I have when I will need to used certain values in math operations.

Comment: Note that you're missing a semicolon after forward declaration `void menu(int option)` which is never later defined.

Comment: You may want to look at the function `get_int_from_user` in [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70818264/12149471). That may be what you are looking for. This function of mine will first read a line of input with `std::getline`, then convert the string to a number using `std::stoi` with full input validation, and if the input is invalid, the user will automatically be reprompted.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Note that this is the expected behavior though. It makes a lot of sense to skip all whitespace -- for example, imagine your program reads actually from a file; then this leniency imposes fewer restrictions on the specific file layout. All values can be in one line, or each on their own. It wouldn't matter provided the data is all there, in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I validate that an user enter a value (int) instead of skip with the enter key

The trick is to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read an entire line into a `std::string`.

```cpp
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
if (s.empty()) {
    // error...
}
```

`getline` extracts characters from an input stream, and copies them to a string. The overload used above has two parameters.

1. The first is a reference to an input stream. This is the stream `getline` reads from.
2. The second is a reference to a `std::string`. This is the string `getline` copies to.

When a newline character (`'\n'`) is encountered, `getline` stops. The newline character is extracted from the stream, and discarded, without appending it to the string.

`getline` returns the input-stream reference (i.e., its first parameter). This can be tested to see whether `getline` somehow failed (usually because it was invoked with an input stream that was at end-of-file).

After a line has been input with `getline`, you can parse it further by constructing an *input string stream* (`istringstream`) from it.

In the snippet below, variable `iss` is an `istringstream` that is constructed from string `s`. Expressions such as `iss >> value` work exactly like `std::cin >> value`, except they read from a stringstream, rather than the keyboard.

```cpp
std::istringstream iss{ s };
int value{};
if (!(iss >> value) {
    // error...
}
```

A more sophisticated approach checks the `istringstream` to make sure that the number is followed only by whitespace. Entries such as `1 x` are rejected.

This approach uses the I/O manipulator `std::ws` to read and discard trailing whitespace, and then checks that the `istringstream` is at end-of-file (i.e., it is out of characters).

```cpp
std::istringstream iss{ s };
int value{};
if ((iss >> value) && !iss.eof())
    iss >> std::ws;
if (iss.fail() || !iss.eof()) {
    // error...
}
```

That's how function `getline_int` works below.

##### A function to input an integer from the keyboard

Most programmers have a function similar to `tbx::get_int` or `tbx::getline_int` (below) that they use to get input from the keyboard. Both functions combine input and validation, looping until a valid entry is made.

- `tbx::get_int` uses operator `>>` for stream input. Although `get_int` does not trap blank lines, it can be useful when a line of input contains more than one value.
- `tbx::getline_int` uses `std::getline` for stream input. Because it is built around `std::getline`, it can trap blank lines, which it rejects as invalid. Use function `getline_int` when a line of input contains a single value.

Optional arguments for `min` and `max` allow the caller to specify the range for valid entries.

- When parameter `min` is omitted, it defaults to `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, which effectively means there is no lower limit.
- Similarly, when parameter `max` is omitted, it defaults to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, which means there is no upper limit.
- When an entry is out of range, a carefully crafted error message mentions `min` and `max` only when they are different from their default values.

Parameters `ist` and `ost`, respectively, default to `std::cin` and `std::cout`. It is useful to have them as parameters in case you want to use other streams during testing.

The functions are declared in header `tbx.console.h`, which also contains other, similar, functions that are used for keyboard input.

##### `tbx.console.h`

```cpp
#pragma once
// tbx.console.h
// Functions used for keyboard I/O
// 
// These functions use `operator>>` for stream input.
// Use them when a line contains more than one input.
//    - get_int 
//    - get_double 
// 
// These functions use `std::getline` for stream input.
// Use them when a line contains a single input.
//    - getline_int
//    - getline_double
//    - getline_yes_no 
//    - press_enter_to_continue
// 
// These functions allow the user to cancel an input operation 
// by pressing Enter on a blank line.
//    - getline_int_or_cancel
//    - getline_double_or_cancel
//
// ...

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

namespace tbx
{
    int get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    int getline_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    // ...
}
// end file: tbx.console.h
```

##### `tbx.console.cpp`

```cpp
// tbx.console.cpp
// Functions used for keyboard I/O

#include <format>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include "tbx.console.h"

namespace tbx
{
    //======================================================================
    // get_int
    //======================================================================
    int get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int const min,
        int const max,
        std::istream& ist,
        std::ostream& ost)
    {
        int n{};
        for (;;)
        {
            ost << prompt;
            if (!(ist >> n))
            {
                ist.clear();
                ist.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
            }
            else if (n < min || n > max)
            {
                ost << std::format("Invalid entry: {}. Please reenter.\n", n);
                if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min() &&
                    max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must be integers between {} and {}.\n\n", min, max);
                else if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must not be less than {}.\n\n", min);
                else if (max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must not be greater than {}.\n\n", max);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    //======================================================================
    // getline_int
    //======================================================================
    int getline_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int const min,
        int const max,
        std::istream& ist,
        std::ostream& ost)
    {
        int n;
        for (;;)
        {
            ost << prompt;
            std::string s;
            if (!std::getline(ist, s))
                throw std::runtime_error("get_int: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.");
            if (s.empty())
            {
                ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n"
                    "Blank lines are not allowed.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            std::istringstream iss{ s };
            if ((iss >> n) && !iss.eof())
                iss >> std::ws;
            if (iss.fail() || !iss.eof())
            {
                ost << "Invalid entry: " << std::quoted(s) << ". Please reenter.\n\n";
            }
            else if (n < min || n > max)
            {
                ost << std::format("Invalid entry: {}. Please reenter.\n", n);
                if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min() &&
                    max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must be integers between {} and {}.\n\n", min, max);
                else if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must not be less than {}.\n\n", min);
                else if (max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                    ost << std::format("Entries must not be greater than {}.\n\n", max);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    // ...
}
// end file: tbx.console.cpp
```

##### Each menu option is a function call

Here is a demo program that uses function `tbx::getline_int` in an implementation of the BMI menu from the OP. Each menu option is handled by a function call.

`std::unreachable()` is a C++23 feature that allows you to identify to the compiler those parts of a program that are unreachable by design. See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) for more info.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "tbx.console.h"

void personal_information() {
    std::cout << "Under construction...\n\n";
}
void physical_information() {
    std::cout << "Under construction...\n\n";
}
void calculate_BMI() {
    std::cout << "Under construction...\n\n";
}
void display_result() {
    std::cout << "Under construction...\n\n";
}
void main_menu()
{
    const char* const menu
    {
        "BMI Calculator"
        "\n 1. Personal Information"
        "\n 2. Physical Information"
        "\n 3. Calculate BMI"
        "\n 4. Result"
        "\n 5. Exit"
        "\n\n"
    };
    enum { PersonalInformation = 1, PhysicalInformation, CalculateBMI, Result, Exit };
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << menu;
        int op{ tbx::getline_int("Choice? ", 1, 5) };
        std::cout << '\n';
        switch (op)
        {
        case PersonalInformation:
            personal_information();
            break;
        case PhysicalInformation:
            physical_information();
            break;
        case CalculateBMI:
            calculate_BMI();
            break;
        case Result:
            display_result();
            break;
        case Exit:
            std::cout << "Exiting...\n\n";
            return;
        default:
            std::unreachable();
        }
    }
    std::unreachable();
}
int main()
{
    main_menu();
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output from a sample run

Note that the blank input line is detected and flagged.

```
BMI Calculator
 1. Personal Information
 2. Physical Information
 3. Calculate BMI
 4. Result
 5. Exit

Choice?
Invalid entry. Please reenter.
Blank lines are not allowed.

Choice? 5

Exiting...
```